# How to change the status bar color at Material3 theme when scrolling？

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner Android develpoer, and my native language is no English. Please forgive me if I am wrong.
I am developing a simple application using Material Design 3 theme. I want to change the defaule toolbar color, but the status bar color doesn't change with the color I set to toolbar.
When I ccrolling the window, it's someting like this.
[the status bar color doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIDE4.jpg)

The code is :

themes.xml

```
    <style name="Theme.SodaMusic" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
          ....
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
                app:titleCentered="true"
                app:titleTextAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceTitleMedium" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

        ...
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```